# customTabBarController not a structure or a union?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am geeting an error customTabBarController not a structure or union?
What the reason for this kind of error?

Many Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not defined in your class, or you did not #import the header.

Comment: i did imported the header file and not sure about the declearation part. Can you please explain. Thanks